# Command line equivalent of IntelliJ IDEA "VCS → Update Project" with Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA 13, the <kbd>VCS</kbd> menu contains the <kbd>Update Project</kbd> option. When using Git, this brings up the following dialog:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Update Project dialog]

I find that the UpdateType="Rebase" and Clean="Stash" options behave perfectly for my workflow. Now I need the equivalent on the command line, for use outside of IDEA.

I know that just the first part would be:

```
git pull --rebase
```

But how do I combine that with the Clean option?

The IDEA option also works perfectly with a mix of staged and unstaged changes. They are restored exactly as-is. This leads me to think there is something more going on than just a simple `git stash`.

---

Side Note: When I invoke the option in IDEA, I see this message being printed to the Version Control console, but I can't figure out how it ties in with the selected options.

```
git fetch origin --progress --prune
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't do it in a single command.  Need three:

```
git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop
```

Meaning... "create a stash, and if successfull, do a pull --rebase, and if successful, apply the stash back to the working tree and drop it".

If the `pull --rebase` fails, the stash won't get applied, but will stay stashed (ready for a `git stash pop` after you fix whatever's causing the `pull` to fail).

If you want to re-stage previously staged changes:

```
git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop --index
```

If you want to stash untracked files as well:

```
git stash --include-untracked && git pull --rebase && git stash pop
```

or

```
git stash --include-untracked && git pull --rebase && git stash pop --index
```

if you also want to re-stage previously staged changes.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why IDEA does the whole `fetch --prune` thing then? That's what led me to question the obvious.

Comment: `fetch --prune` means remove any branches that are tracking remote branches that no longer exist on the remote.  `git pull` does a fetch first, but doesn't allow you to pass the `--prune` option, so I guess IDEA does an explicit `fetch` in order to do the pruning.

Comment: `git fetch <remote> --prune` will fetch the remote, and delete any remote tracking branches for branches that have disappeared on the remote. It doesn't have anything to do with what happens to your working copy, just with how it manages the branches named `refs/remotes/<remote>/<branch>`.

Comment: This answer does not work if there are unstaged changes. IDEA works fine even with a mix of staged and unstaged changes - everything is restored as-is. I think we are still missing some magic here.

Comment: If you mean it does not re-stage your pre-staged changes, you can use the `--index` option to `git stash pop` to re-stage them. I'll update the answer.